# enable curl in xampp, windows

Tags: php, curl, xampp

trying to enable curl in xampp 3.0.12 in windows environment.

Updated the `php.ini` in the php folder to enable curl, and there is no `php.ini` file in the `apache/bin` folder.

`phpinfo()` says:

- loaded configuration file: `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`
- curl support:enbaled
- curl information: 7.24.0

and when i try to run a `http_get()` command php says:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get()

Restarted both windows and xampp several times to update the changes.

Would be grateful for some advice, as I searched through similar topics on the web but can't get any further.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function `http_get()` belongs to the [pecl http](http://php.net/manual/de/http.install.php) extension and not to the curl extension. Refer to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) of the curl extension to learn how you can use it to retrieve documents via http. You'll also find a lot of posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20curl)

Also note, that the function [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) can be used to get documents over http in a very simple way. Although it is limited it will fit in much cases. To retrieve a page you can issue:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.server.com/page.html');
```